# Graphs with Linear Algebra: What is meant by a loop here?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I'm learning linear algebra through Prof. Gilbert Strang's lectures on MIT OCW, I need a little help understanding what exactly is meant by a loop:
[image]

The Incidence matrix for this graph is $$ A= \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$ (columns for nodes and rows for edges)

A has rank=3, therefore A has two dependent rows and dimension of $ N(A^T)=2$. The professor says that the number of loops in this graph is 2 because there are two vectors in the basis for $N(A^T).$

He counts that there are actually three closed paths: the two triangles and the entire outer quadrilateral. He says that the number of loops isn't three, because the row combination that corresponds to the outer quadrilateral is a linear combination of the 2 basis vectors of $ N(A^T)$ (which we chose as the combination that correspond to the two triangles).

So loop here doesn't literally refer to the number of closed paths, but something along the lines of 'independent' closed paths. So, can someone confirm that this is what he means, and provide me with a more accurate definition for 'loop' that I can put down in my notes?

Comment: $N(A^T)$ is nullspace of A transposed, i.e combinations of rows of A that give zero. Is that what you wanted? I do not know what a kernel is...

Comment: I think the paths need to be closed (having an edge from the last to the first vertex) and feature no repetition of a vertex.

Comment: Yes, the kernel is the set of all vectors that are mapped to zero.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something about this context: it seems like there are not three closed *directed* paths, in fact there are no closed directed paths. Is that not a problem?

Comment: I believe the arrows do indicate some orientation but no direction restriction.

Comment: The directions assigned to the edges are arbitrary... ex: edge1, edge2 and -edge3 counts as a loop

Comment: Yes, the "number of loops" is an informal way to say "dimension of the cycle space" here, rather than a literal number of cycles.